# Flagged a question for migration but it got declined. Should it be deleted as off-topic instead?

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging

I flagged the question [*How do I remove tags from my Tumblr theme?*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53690/how-do-i-remove-tags-from-my-tumblr-theme). Since this is a coding problem I recommended migrating it to Stack Overflow. However the flag got declined. I can only guess this is due the quality of the question and likeness of creating dublicates or something else.

The questions topic is not related to something one can setup inside tumblr as a webapp. A change like this almost ever has to be done inside the tumblr theme code.

Should it be closed as off-topic instead?

Answer (score 2):

It's not off topic.

Tumblr is a web application, so a question about how to configure it is very much on topic for us.

Yes you have to write code, but it would probably get closed very quickly on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What the author of the question requested has nothing to do with how tumblr itself is configured. It's theme developement. Why would it be closed on SO?

Comment: @Klein General theme development *should*  be OK, but it has to be couched in the right way. SO can  be fickle at times.